# Подскажите простой способ развертывания Javafx приложений

Tags: javafx

Как просто и удобно для пользователей развертывать JavaFX приложения. Кто может просто и понятно объяснить как это сделать? Имеется ввиду что у меня уже есть готовый jar-файл.

Answer (score 1):

Из платных можно выделить **install builder**, **InstallShield**, а из бесплатных **lzPack** и **NSIS**.

Так же если вы используете среду разработки NetBeans то там есть специальный модуль с собственным пакетом инсталлятора.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Пробовал я использовать NetBeans, но пока вопрос остался открытым. Если выбирать в Idea или NetBeans сборку как "JavaFX Application", то создаются файлы jnlp, html, jar. Но запустить их в браузере не удается, пишет что надо обновить Java и отсылает на сайт загрузки, после чего пишет что теперь JavaFX встроена в Java8. А мне надо чтобы мое приложение работало в браузере.